# The relation between linewidth and energy of an emitted photon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I was looking at Heisenberg's uncertainty problems and came across a question asking for the linewidth of an emitted photon. I seem to remember that linewidth is measured in units of energy but I am unsure how to go about calculating it.

Answer (score 1):

You need an infinite amount of time to measure frequency with perfect accuracy. Conversely, an instanteous measurement gives no information about frequency.  So the time-span of the measurement needs to be specified before you can say anything about the line-width. Line-width often refers to frequency bandwidth and thus to a range of energies via Planck's constant, h$\Delta$f = $\Delta$E. The uncertainty principle is usually quoted as $\Delta$E. $\Delta$T = h/4$\pi$. In contrast to the classical position-momentum uncertainty principle, there is less clarity in the interpretation of the [energy-time uncertainty](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/uncertainty.html).

Answer (score 0):

While the question is vague, I think I can offer some clarifying remarks.   If you're measuring the line width of an atomic transition through repeated measurements of the energy of a photon (which equals it's frequency), then the distribution that you'll get in those energies will be a measure of various aspects of the atom(s) being measured.  If it's just a single atom, then the linewdith is determined by the lifetime of the upper-state.  If this is a collection of atoms in a gas then various broadening mechanisms exist that will make the distribution wider.